# dotMemory The resource loader failed to find MUI file. When try to profile local IIS

Tags: iis, profiling, jetbrains-ide, dotmemory

When I try to connect to Local IIS with dotMemory I am getting error

---

### dotMemory

Unable to start profiling.

### The resource loader failed to find MUI file.

### OK

I am using v.2018.2.3

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ChrFin yes look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved an issue. Problem was that my display language is English(Australia) but after changing it to English USA and restarting my pc all works as expected